# How can I rename a tag in Bit.ly?

Tags: bit.ly

I create some Tags for our newsletter. Then the newsletter name changed ;-)

Can I rename a Bit.ly tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe you are able to rename the tag directly, so the workaround you need to do is the following to change the tag from `aaa` to `bbb`:

- Change the filter to display *Only archived* and *Tags > `bbb`*. Choose apply
- It now displays all the archived links with this tag, retag each link with your newly created tag, `bbb`, and remove the references to `aaa`
- Hit the `X` on the `Archived` filter above the links, and repeat the process of retagging with `bbb`, and removing references to `aaa`

Now since you have removed all references to `aaa`, and added references to `bbb`, you have renamed this tag. Tags not used doesn't display anywhere anymore.

Comment: Sometimes the removed tags disappear, and sometimes notes. Bit.ly is not entirely consistent in its behaviour here...